# Child inside NestedScrollView not cover full height of screen

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout, android-nestedscrollview

I am using NestedScrollView in my fragment. In my xml inside a RelativeLayout but it is not covering full height of screen.

Below is my code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@color/black"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@color/red_error_color"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

when run the code only black background is visible but not red as my child view background is red.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Try to add this line of code on your nestedscrollview

```
android:fillViewport="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Remove:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: I suppose in a more general case android:fillViewport="true" is sufficient. (worked for me)

Comment: no need to add kayout_behavior att