# Constraint layout not matching parent in Nested scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, constraints, android-constraintlayout, android-coordinatorlayout

Constraint layout not matching parent in Nestedscrollview and all in coordinate layout.
So, i am including layout file in Coordinate layout .
Below is the code and Image of Layout .
[image: Screenshot]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="true"

   >
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/delivery_tv_label"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Delivery"
           android:textSize="14sp"
           android:textAlignment="center"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/rating_tv_label"
           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="5"
           />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rating_tv_label"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Overall Rating"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/delivery_tv_label"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="5"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delivery_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="21 Mins"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/delivery_tv_label"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/rating_tv_label"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="5"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rating_tv_label"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/delivery_tv"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rating_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4.2"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"

                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/star_img"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_24"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"

                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rets"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="@string/large_text"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_item_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linear_layout"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This layout is one of the child of CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Edit :** I'm going to elaborate more on why this is the solution.

The reason you need `fillViewPort` is you've a `RecyclerView` inside which means you want to fill the available space with it as you've also used `0dp`. But, the problem is without `fillViewPort`, it won't behave like fill available space (`0dp`) and will work as `wrap_content`. So, the moment you set `fillViewPort`, it fills all the available space even with less content. Check [these images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBevD.jpg) for its working.

You can also check similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42996774/8244632).

---

Remember ScrollView child's default height is `wrap_content` and hence its child layout `ConstraintLayout` is also taking `wrap_content` as the height as mentioned in below image of the warning IDE shows.
[image]
This warning is not shown in case of `NestedScrollView` but its child still acts as `wrap_content`.

So, you just have to set `android:fillViewport="true"` in `NestedScrollView` as:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
    ...
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Setting `fillViewPort` will do the trick as it will act like `match_parent` or in your case, `0dp`.